# Calculations involving mixed type elements in columns - np.nan, float, string elements

Tags: python, string, pandas, dataframe, nan

I have a dataframe where columns include mixed type elements and I need to do some calculations among them. Assume this dataframe:

```
A=[20, np.nan, 10, 'give', np.nan, np.nan]
B=[10, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, 10, 'given']

frame=pd.DataFrame(zip(A,B))
frame.columns=['A', 'B']
```

I want to populate the difference of B from A. If I do `frame['diff']=frame['A']-frame['B']` it does not give the result I need. Instead, the result I would want is in the 'desired diff' column.

Basically, if A or B has a number, then B or A should be 0. If a string is in A, while B is NaN, then it should write "positive" and, in the vice versa case, it should write "negative". See below:

```
frame
      A      B  diff  desired diff
0    20     10    10            10
1   NaN    NaN   NaN           NaN
2    10    NaN   NaN            10
3  give    NaN   NaN      positive
4   NaN     10   NaN           -10
5   NaN  given   NaN      negative
```

Just for the record, I have tried to implement `np.where` and `np.select` and some conditions such as `np.logical_and(frame['A'].apply(lambda x: isinstance(x, float)), frame['B'].isna())` to achieve the desired output, but without success.

Thanks in advance for your suggestions!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`to_numeric`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.to_numeric.html) with `errors='coerce'` for check non numeric and no missing values and set new values by [`numpy.select`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.select.html) and subtract values by [`Series.sub`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.sub.html) with `fill_value=0` parameter:

```
a = pd.to_numeric(frame['A'], errors='coerce')
m1 = frame['A'].notna()
m2 = a.isna()

b = pd.to_numeric(frame['B'], errors='coerce')
m3 = frame['B'].notna()
m4 = b.isna()

frame['new'] = np.select([m1 & m2, m3 & m4], 
                         ['positive', 'negative'], 
                         default = a.sub(b, fill_value=0))
print (frame)
      A      B       new
0    20     10      10.0
1   NaN    NaN       nan
2    10    NaN      10.0
3  give    NaN  positive
4   NaN     10     -10.0
5   NaN  given  negative
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use a long apply, which I would not recommend:

```
frame['diff'] = (frame.fillna(0)
                 .apply(lambda x: x.A-x.B if (isinstance(x.A, (int, float)) & isinstance(x.B, (int, float)))
                        else ('positive' if (isinstance(x.A, str) & (x.B == 0)) else 'negative'),
                        axis=1)
                 .replace(0, np.nan))

      A      B      diff
0    20     10        10
1   NaN    NaN       NaN
2    10    NaN        10
3  give    NaN  positive
4   NaN     10       -10
5   NaN  given  negative
```